# How to calculate the force of attraction experienced by free electrons in metals?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

The electrons must experience a net force due to the atoms and other electrons in the system even if its free,that is why it is still in the system and is moving randomly(i think).How to calculate it?

Answer (score 0):

For a simplified, semi-classical model, see [Drude model.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model)  With this approach the interior of the metal is shielded from the effects of the bound particles, and they can be ignored except when (a) there is a collision, in which case the free electrons randomly change direction and momentum, and (b) when one comes to the surface of the metal, which is a barrier, with escape requiring energy greater than the work function of the metal.

This model gives correct results for some properties, but is wrong for others; the calculations are described in the introductory chapters of most solid state text books.

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult question and you hardly show any effort to arrive closer to an answer. This makes it hard to estimate your level of understanding of quantum many particle systems. Also your question is very generic.

The electrons are free in the sense that they are not localised to any particular atom and that the effect of electron-electron scattering is minimal. This is true at large distancs scale. Deviations from this free behaviour occur at small scale. The screening by inner electrons in incomplete so part of the time the conduction electrons feel the nuclear charge, which is higher than the ionic charge. This is the origin of the work needed to remove a conduction electron entirely from the metal, usually a few electronvolt.

Physicists nowadays use the local density approximation to disentangle the high level of electron correlation in for example metals. You can find a description here :
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local-density_approximation and here:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_functional_theory.

For a introduction to a quantum mechanical https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_functional_theory see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_heap_and_Fermi_hole.

Comment: I just finished high school and the first chapter of first part of feynman lectures,so i lack in depth knowledge that is why my description of the question is too vague.

Comment: I found it hard to give a more specific answer - using my phone at 130km/hr on the highway - not driving myself. Let me know any questions that will come up while reading the Wikipedia articles.

Comment: Thank you,just one question(not related to this),is there any minimum electric field strength for an electromagnetic wave to interact with electrons?